# Sending a variable in PHP with a form to the same page, but I am getting error

Tags: php, database, forms, variables

Please Help, I am coding a page with PHP where users choose a subject, click on the link and are directed to a page where they can comment on.The user make use of a small form to comment on a subject. I am trying to submit the form to the same page. So that the comment that the user submitted will display immediatly. I am sending a variable with the form using the GET method, but I am getting:
Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1,

but it is writing to my database, just not displaying the data

Here is my code(before head):

```
<?php 

// GET subject_id from previous page and see if it has been set
if (isset($_GET['subj'])) {  
subject_id = $_GET['subj'];
} else {
$subject_id = NULL;
}


// process form that was submitted to same page
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$subject_id = mysql_prep($_GET['subj']);
$commentbox = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['commentbox']));

$query = "INSERT INTO comments (
subject_id, content
) VALUES (
{$subject_id}, '{$commentbox}'
)";


if ($result = mysql_query($query, $connection)) {
// as is, $message will still be discarded on the redirect
$message = "The page was successfully created.";
redirect_to("blog_subject.php");
} else {
$message = "The page was unsuccessfully created.";
redirect_to("blog_subject.php");
}
}
?>
```

......and then the code to display the subject,comments and form...

```
<?php
// Retrieving Subject Name from subjects database
global $connection;
if (isset($_GET['subj'])) {$subject_id = $_GET['subj'];} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE subject_id = {$subject_id}";

$result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if (!$result_set) {die("Database query Failed: " . mysql_error());}

if ($subject_set = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {

echo $subject_set['subject_name'];

} else {

return NULL;

}
?>
<br />
<?php
// Retrieving Comments from comments database

global $connection;

$subject_id = $_GET['subj'];

$comment_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE subject_id =
{$subject_id}", $connection);

if (!$comment_set) {
die("Database query Failed: " . mysql_error());
}

echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";
while ($comment_for_subject = mysql_fetch_array($comment_set)) {
echo "<li>{$comment_for_subject["content"]}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";   
?>
<br /> 

<form action="blog_subject.php?subj=<?php echo $subject_id_van_vorige_bladsy; ?>"
method="post">
<textarea name="commentbox" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is subject_id a string or a number? if it is a string you need to escape it like this:

```
$comment_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE subject_id = '{$subject_id}'", $connection);
```

If that is not it, please do an echo on $comment_set and post the output of that

Comment: then there is something wrong with the code that creates the link. There should not be this {...} stuff. Your Script is expecting a number here

Comment: When I echo &comment_set I get Resource id #9;

Comment: But subject_id is a number. What I am trying to do is have subjects on one page and if you click on a subject you move to the page with that subject and its comments. Everything to this point works, but when a user submit a comment this is one I get the error.

Comment: yea was looking in the wrong direction here some hours ago. As said in my last comment, look into the code that creates that link on blog.php. This gives the strange {$subject.....} string as subj, but your sql server wants to have a number there. You should be abled to see that if you echo $subject_id before the query. This should be a number. If not than the broken link is your Problem, and i bet it is.

Comment: Yes you right!!! I am echo subject_id but nothing is displayed. The subject_id I am sending with my form in the action part is not doing its job, but I did this before and it worked? What am I doing wrong. Here is my code: <form action="blog_subject.php?subj=<?php echo $subject_id; ?>" method="post"> if I put the $subject_id in {} then I get a parse error?

Comment: but why the {}? Seen those alot lately but not sure what those are for. Anyways ... if $subject_id is a number this should work like it stands above. What link does this create? Wheres the problem?