# Trouble with outputing data in the database using PHP

Tags: php, database

Please help,
I am calling data from my database in a function and want to display it to the user in a table format. What I'm aiming to achieve is getting all the names in my database to look something like this:

```
John   Peter   James    Steven
Jess   Syndey  Monique  Lynda
```

but what I am getting is this:

```
John   John   John   John
Peter  Peter  Peter  Peter
James  James  James  James
etc    etc    etc    etc
```

Here is my code:

```
function public_navigation($sel_subject, $sel_page, $public = true) {
  $output = "<table border=\"1\">";
  $subject_set = get_all_subjects($public);
  $column_count = mysql_num_fields($subject_set);
  while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)) {
    $output .= "<tr>";
    for($column_num = 0; $column_num < $column_count; $column_num++) {
      $output .= "<td><a href=\"index.php?subj=" . urlencode($subject["id"]) . 
                 "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></td>";
    }           
  }
  $output .= "</tr></table>";
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: this is caused by the for loop. What are you trying to iterate in there?

Comment: I am trying to display all the names that is in my database on my website eg. 1 2 3 4 and then moving on to the next line 5 6 7 8 but all that I'm getting is 1 1 1 1 and on the next line 2 2 2 2 and so on and so on what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please add more example code showing what you have in the DB, and what your actual query looks like.

Comment: We need to see your actual query, there seems to be a problem with your get_all_subjects(); function. I don't think it returns what you think it returns ;) Also why not use a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function public_navigation ($sel_subject, $sel_page, $public = true, $column_count = 4) {
  $output = '<table border="1">'; // Start table element
  $subject_set = get_all_subjects($public); // Get data
  for ($i = 1; $subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set); $i++) { // Loop data witha counter
    if ($i == 1) {
      // Start of a new row
      $output .= '<tr>';
    }
    // Cell for this record
    $output .= '<td><a href="index.php?subj='.htmlspecialchars(urlencode($subject["id"])).'">'.htmlspecialchars($subject["menu_name"]).'</a></td>';
    if ($i >= $column_count) {
      // End of this row
      $i = 0;
      $output .= '</tr>';
    }
  }
  if ($i > 1 && $i <= $column_count) {
    // Pad with an empty cell if needed
    $colspan = ($column_count + 1) - $i;
    $output .= "<td colspan=\"$colspan\" /></tr>";
  }
  $output .= '</table>'; // End of table
  return $output; // Return output
}
```

Comment: wow that construction with the for is a clever one, never seen that before, +1 for that, but i like my inner stuff with the % better

Comment: Hey maybe you guys can help me on one other problem I am having, i am only a beginner with this and you are pro. I posted my problem on this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064170/sending-a-variable-in-php-with-a-form-to-the-same-page-but-i-am-getting-error) Can you please help me with this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

When having database query troubles, you should always post the query along with it. Its fine if you disguise the field names and such, but it's hard to pinpoint the problem without more details.

For starters, it seems you're sorting by name, even though you don't want to. Removing "ORDER BY [FIELDNAME]" from the query should fix this.

Secondly, it seems you are 'grouping' something or 'joining' something without filtering out the double results. At least, that's the most common problem when you see the same rows popping up multiple times. This can be fixed by using a "DISTINCT([FIELDNAME])" in your query.

And, on a sidenote, why are you using get_all_subjects() and mysql_num_fields() instead of just mysql_query()? In fact, I'm not even sure what get_all_subjects() does, php.net doesn't have it, and it definitely isn't a standard php function...

```
function public_navigation($sel_subject, $sel_page, $public = true) {
  $RowCount = 1;
  $SQL = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY");
  while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($SQL) {
    $RowHTML = '<td>[CONTENTS OF CELL]</td>'.(($RowCount % 4) ? '</tr><tr>' : '');
    $RowCount++;
    }

 return eregi_replace('<tr></tr>','','<table><tr>'.$output.'</tr></table>');
 }
```

Comment: Sorry about that stupid from my side, thank you for your time and help, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested loops, the while always reads a new line, and the for outputs it as often as there are rows. Open the

```
<tr>
```

before the while and close it after the while. Then set

```
$i=0;
```

before the while.

In the while do this:

```
if ($i%5 == 0)
{
    echo "</tr><tr>";
}
$i++;
```

This should do it.